# Why can't I update the table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

The code is simple, but When I look up the value after the update, it remains the same

```
Update tble_SalesReps_TR 
Set Salary=100000 
where SalesRepID=1
```

But when I check it later with  the following code

```
Select Salary 
from tble_SalesReps_TR
Where SalesRepID=1
```

It shows me

```
85000
```

What could be the reasons for this?

Comment: What is the result of your update command? Any error or message?

Comment: Do you have any triggers on the SalesReps table?

Comment: Transaction being rolledback by any means? during the execution
Another process updating the same row?
have you tried the execution within the same batch something like :

    Select Salary from tble_SalesReps_TR Where SalesRepID=1
    go
    Update tble_SalesReps_TR Set Salary=100000 where SalesRepID=1
    go
    Select Salary from tble_SalesReps_TR Where SalesRepID=1